# Excel VBA Query get date from MS-Access column and row not match with the sequence

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConnectDB_Select()
'Path
Dim strPath As String

    'Provider
    Dim strProv As String
    
    'Connection String
    Dim strConn As String
    
    'Connection
    Dim Conn As New Connection
    
    'RecordSet
    Dim rsQry As New Recordset
    
    'SQL Query
    Dim strQry As String
    
    'SQL HEADER FIELD
    Dim Field
    Dim lCol As Long
    
    
    '-----------------------------------
    
    strPath = "D:\Access\XH Voyager_Conversion Template.accdb"
    strProv = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    strConn = "Provider=" & strProv & "Data Source=" & strPath
    
    'Connection Open
    Conn.Open strConn
    strQry = "Select * from [Main Component_CT]"
    rsQry.Open strQry, Conn
    
    wksData.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsQry
    
    lCol = 0
    For Each Field In rsQry.Fields
    wksData.Range("A1").Offset(, lCol) = Field.Name
    lCol = lCol + 1
    Next Field

End Sub
```

greetings to all expert,

Currently I'm creating an excel VBA get data from MS Access but the only I wish the column in Excel should match with Ms Access.  Anyone able to assist? thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output as formatted text tables https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support. Edit statement so it makes sense - what does this mean: "the only I wish the column in Excel should match with MS Access"?

Comment: Need to Set wksData object variable: `Set wksData = Worksheets("sheet name here")`. Code works for me after that edit.